# IMacro JavaScript; Loop on IF else statement

Tags: javascript, imacros

```
for(var i=0;i<1;i++)
{ 
    iimPlay(macro_var)
    var extract=iimGetLastExtract();
    if(extract.toLowerCase()=="incorrect security code entered!")
    {
        iimDisplay("wrong") 
    }
    else
    {
        iimDisplay("right")
    }
}
```

That's my imacro code (Javascript File)
If i get wrong how i do get it to try again until it reaches right?

Comment: instead of `for` you could use `while(true)`, then `continue` inside the `if` and `break` inside the `else`

Comment: I'm new to this, Don't really understand how to get that working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you don't want to wait between executions, there are a couple of ways you could do this. The quickest one would be:

```
while(true) {
    iimPlay(macro_var);
    var extract = iimGetLastExtract();
    if (extract.toLowerCase() == "incorrect security code entered!") {
        iimDisplay("wrong");
        continue;
    } else {
        iimDisplay("right");
        break;
    }
}
```

In this way, when the extracted value is wrong you restart the loop. If instead it's right, you break out of the loop.